# MySQL check if parent and child field matches before inserting foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to enforce a check in a child table where a field must have the same value as the parent to allow the foreign key insertion?

For example, say I have the table below

```
Parent Table
-------------
id
field1
field7

Child Table
-------------
id
field1
field2
parent_id (foreign key to parent table column "id")
field3
```

I only want to allow a parent_id to be inserted in child table if "field1" in both Child and Parent tables have the same value.

I was thinking of just handling this constraint in the application logic, but I was curious if MySQL had a way to enforce this.

EDIT: In this scenario, the Child table has a one-to-many foreign key relationship with the Parent table. The Child table column `parent_id` references the Parent table column `id`. So in addition to this, I'd only want to insert child table values where the given Child table "field1" value match the given "parent_id" referenced value "field1"

Comment: Yes, it is foreign key constraints, can be established using the InnoDB engine. [see this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/5.7/en/example-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Is the field1 in the parent table a unique column?

Comment: @CharifDZ no it doesn't have a unique constraint

Answer (score 1):

This is called a foreign key constraint.  The best approach is to define the `id` in the parent table as the primary key:

```
create table parent (
    id <whatever type> primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Most databases require that the referred to key be a primary key or unique.  Although MySQL extends this to any key (i.e. any column(s) with an index), stick with primary/unique keys.

In the child table, you can then declare the foreign key reference:

```
alter table child add constraint fk_child_parent
    foreign key (parent_id) references parent (id);
```

EDIT:

I don't think it is a good idea to repeat values across tables.  It is better to look them up as necessary.  You can, however, do what you want with a foreign key:

```
create table parent (
    id <whatever type> primary key,
    field1 . . .,
    . . .
    unique (field1, id)
);

alter table child add constraint fk_child_parent
    foreign key (field1, parent_id) references parent (field1, id);
```

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear on this in the question, but in this scenario, the "parent_id" in the child table is a foreign key on the parent table "id." The field1 column doesn't interact in the relationship, but I'd want to check to make sure the two values match aside from the normal foreign key that child table's "parent_id" and parent table's "id" have

Comment: @GetOtterHere . . . That is a pretty minor change.  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: How does this add a constraint for the "field1" column between the two tables though?